# Failure creating a function same as stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

This is my stored procedure which I was able to create

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllStaffCollectiveAttendanceByMonth]
@Month nvarchar(9)
AS
BEGIN

Declare @StartDate DATE,
@EndDate DATE

;WITH CteMonths(n, m) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'January' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'February' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'March' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'April' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'May' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'June' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'July' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 'August' UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 'September' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 'October' UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 'November' UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 'December'
  )
SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, n - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 
@EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
FROM CteMonths
WHERE m = @month

SELECT
    StaffAttendance.StaffId,
    DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) AS [ForMonth], @StartDate AS StartDate, @EndDate AS EndDate,
    (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 1)-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalWorkingDays,
    SUM(StaffAttendance.AttendanceStatusId) AS TotalDaysWorked
    FROM StaffAttendance 
    WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND StaffAttendance.AttendanceStatusId = 1 GROUP BY StaffAttendance.StaffId
END


GO
```

This, here, is my function which I am trying to create but can't. Its the same thing as above except for what makes it a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[funcGetAllStaffCollectiveAttendanceByMonth]
(
@Month nvarchar(9)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
Declare @StartDate DATE,
@EndDate DATE

;WITH CteMonths(n, m) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'January' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'February' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'March' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'April' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'May' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'June' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'July' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 'August' UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 'September' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 'October' UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 'November' UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 'December'
  )
SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, n - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 
@EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
FROM CteMonths
WHERE m = @month

SELECT
    StaffAttendance.StaffId,
    DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) AS [ForMonth], @StartDate AS StartDate, @EndDate AS EndDate,
    (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 1)-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalWorkingDays,
    SUM(StaffAttendance.AttendanceStatusId) AS TotalDaysWorked
    FROM StaffAttendance 
    WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND StaffAttendance.AttendanceStatusId = 1 GROUP BY StaffAttendance.StaffId
END
)
```

But this is what I am getting

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you explain the logic in a couple of sentences?

Comment: The `@startDate` is the beginning of the month prior to the month passed as a parameter and the `@endDate` is the end of that month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the syntax for an inline table-valued function but you have multiple statements.

[Comparison of inline and multi-statement table-valued functions.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/discussionofsqlserver/2012/02/15/comparing-inline-and-multistatement-table-valued-functions/)

So you could either refactor to use a single statement (higher performance) or use the multi-statement syntax as described in that link (easier).

If you wanted to do it inline you could do something along these lines (note, I don't have SSMS available right now so there may be some minor syntax errors like unmatched brackets):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[funcGetAllStaffCollectiveAttendanceByMonth]
(
@Month nvarchar(9)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
-- The StartDate should be the first day of the month that is passed as a parameter, in the current year.
-- The EndDate should be the last day of the month which the StartDate begins.
WITH cteDates AS (
    SELECT StartDate = Convert(date, Concat('01', @Month, Convert(varchar(4), DatePart(Year, GetDate()))), 106),
    EndDate = DateAdd(Day, -1, 
        DateAdd(Month, 1, 
            Convert(date, Concat('01', @Month, Convert(varchar(4), DatePart(Year, GetDate()))) , 106)
        )
    )
)

SELECT
    Sa.StaffId,
    DATENAME(MONTH, cteDates.StartDate) AS [ForMonth], 
    cteDates.StartDate, 
    cteDates.EndDate,
    (DATEDIFF(dd, cteDates.StartDate, cteDates.EndDate) + 1)-
        (DATEDIFF(wk, cteDates.StartDate, cteDates.EndDate) * 1)-
        (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, cteDates.StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalWorkingDays,
    SUM(sa.AttendanceStatusId) AS TotalDaysWorked
  FROM StaffAttendance As sa
  JOIN cteDates ON sa.[Date] BETWEEN cteDates.StartDate AND cteDates.EndDate 
  WHERE sa.AttendanceStatusId = 1 
  GROUP BY 
    Sa.StaffId,
    DATENAME(MONTH, cteDates.StartDate), 
    cteDates.StartDate, 
    cteDates.EndDate,
    (DATEDIFF(dd, cteDates.StartDate, cteDates.EndDate) + 1)-
        (DATEDIFF(wk, cteDates.StartDate, cteDates.EndDate) * 1)-
        (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, cteDates.StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
END
)
```

Comment: Is that a limitation in SQL server? That multiple statements can't be used in an ITVF?

Comment: I would like to stick with ITVF. Will you be kind enough and help me there please?

Comment: @fasih I have written a sample, note that I don't have SSMS here so you might need to debug some minor syntax errors. I'd be interested in comparative performance of the stored procedure vs. Inline Table-Valued Function, please share results.

Comment: Sure, will do that shortly. Thanks for help btw.

Comment: `select * from funcGetAllStaffCollectiveAttendanceByMonth('november')` returns a result set for October for some reason.

Comment: @fasih isn't that what you wanted? It was a bit tricky to understand exactly what the procedure is supposed to return with all those `DateAdd()`s and `DateDiff()`s. So it should return results for the month specified in the parameter?

Comment: For function `SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 4 ms.

(7 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.`

Comment: For SP `SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 6 ms, elapsed time = 6 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(7 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 7 ms.`

Comment: Yes, that's what it should be doing. Returning results for the parameter passed. Attendance for November should be displayed if the parameter passed is 'November.'

Comment: @fasih I adjusted the date.

Comment: What it is doing instead is returning result of previous month.